# CSS variables not working in dialog::backdrop

Tags: dialog, modal-dialog, pseudo-element, css-variables

I'm trying to change the background color of a `dialog` element's `backdrop` using a custom CSS property but it won't take. Is this a bug in Chrome or is there a reason for this?

```js
document.querySelector('dialog').showModal();
```

```css
:root {
  --color-backdrop: red;
}

dialog::backdrop {
  background: var(--color-backdrop);
}
```

```html
<dialog>
  <p>This is a dialog. My backdrop should be red.</p>
</dialog>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Updated answer (29/02/2024)

As pointed out by [Wes Goulet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77393321/7443903), this will change (or has changed) and we may have the expected behaviour of the original poster. So, the following probably works on all major browsers:

```js
document.querySelector('dialog').showModal();
```

```css
:root {
  --color-backdrop: red;
}

dialog::backdrop {
  background: var(--color-backdrop);
}
```

```html
<dialog>
  <p>This is a dialog. My backdrop should be red.</p>
</dialog>
```

We can check its status following these links:

- [web platform tests for "::backdrop inherits"](https://wpt.fyi/results/html/semantics/interactive-elements/the-dialog-element/backdrop-inherits.html?label=experimental&label=master&aligned);
- [Chromium Bug #40569411](https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40569411);
- [Gecko/Firefox Bug #1855668](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1855668);
- [WebKit Bug #263834](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=263834);

### Outdated answer

The [spec](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#::backdrop-pseudo-element) states the following about `::backdrop` pseudo-element:

> It does not inherit from any element and is not inherited from. No restrictions are made on what properties apply to this pseudo-element either.

And to [quote Xindorn Quan](https://github.com/whatwg/fullscreen/issues/124#issuecomment-377653973), a member of WHATWG, regarding CSS Custom Properties:

> CSS variables are propagated via inheritance into descendants, so if a pseudo-element doesn't inherit from anything, CSS variables which are not defined for the pseudo-element directly would have no effect on the pseudo-element.

Finally, this is one solution for this kind of problem:

```js
document.querySelector('dialog').showModal();
```

```css
::backdrop {
  --color-backdrop: red;
}

dialog::backdrop {
  background: var(--color-backdrop);
}
```

```html
<dialog><p>This is a dialog. My backdrop should be red.</p></dialog>
```

It seems to be useful for multiple modals with `::backdrop`, as a way of organizing their "root", so to speak.

Comment: Oh I see, so it won't inherit custom properties set on `:root` at all... that's a little annoying as we keep all our "config" in one file and they're all set on `:root`. Having to set one specific config variable on `::backdrop` (as well as `:root` as it's used by other things too) will be a little annoying.

Comment: :root, ::backdrop {
  --color-backdrop: red;
}

Then it's available to both

Comment: This solution does not work for css props piercing a shadow dom.

Answer (score 8):

**2023 Update**

The spec has been updated to allow `::backdrop` to inherit from the originating element, which allows backdrop to recognize CSS vars.  Each major browser has bugs for updating their implementation.

- [Web Page Test for ::backdrop respecting CSS vars](https://wpt.fyi/results/html/semantics/interactive-elements/the-dialog-element/backdrop-inherits.html)
- [Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=827397)
- [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1855668)
- [Safari bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=263834)

So soon the OP example will work :)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @TylerH this answer has even more value at least for me rather than accepted one; and i would never read it if it was a comment

Comment: @IliaLiachin This post does not provide a new solution. It only explains an update about a solution provided by the accepted answer. Thus it should be a comment under that answer or a suggested edit to that answer.

Comment: @TylerH people come here to get answers; this answer is exactly what i was looking for when opened this SO link; thus this is a proper answer, at least for me; probably there are more such people, and you're suggesting to make their lives harder just because you don't like this answer; ...vegetarians style

Comment: So do what I did and upvote this answer.