# :root variables not available on :before element

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I got a lot of CSS variables assigned to :root but these are not accessible inside my :before element. I'm not able to find anything on this online.

When inspecting the parent of the :before element, I see all my :root variables in the bottom of the styles panel in google dev tools. See screenshots below.

My CSS

```
    &__meta {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: var(--text-color);

    &-author {
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
    &-primary-cat:before {
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: var(--text-color);
        border-radius: 50%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
}
```

Chrome dev tools parent CSS

[image]

Chrome dev tools :before CSS - all styles excluding the background-color are applied to the :before element as expected

[image]

Comment: Please provide a runnable minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the issue, from what I can see in your code, it seems fine.

Comment: Please use double-colon syntax for pseudo-elements. Single-colon syntax is deprecated.

Answer (score 11):

The answer to a similar question might help: [CSS variables not working in dialog::backdrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58818299/css-variables-not-working-in-dialogbackdrop/63322762#63322762)

The pseudo-elements don't inherit the variables from :root.  It sounds like you need to need to add them to the list where you define them, e.g.

```
:root,
::after,
::before {
    /* Your variables*/
}
```

Comment: THIS ANSWER IS **WRONG** : https://jsfiddle.net/dfmq63g8/

Comment: That sort of works but if you look at your fiddle in devtools it says "--c is not defined" even though it has an effect.  Maybe its a bug in chrome?

Answer (score 1):

#### Define CSS Var/ Custom Property for selector and each pseudo

For now it seems **css vars or custom properties are not inherited from element or parent element selector to its pseudo elements** as well as not inherited to any child element or their pseudo elements.

And as far as I can tell you have to define them twice unfortunately, **including css var/custom property once on the parent element selector and then again for EACH of the pseudo selectors**. There could absolutely be a best practice however I couldn't find one so this set up works for me.

I add my css vars/ custom properties to specific selectors so they can be modified further per element selector as well as it being slightly easier to inspect each element and have your css vars/ custom properties show with your selector.

#### Example Basic CSS Method 1

```
// .example element and its pseudo selectors
.example, .example:before, .example:after, .example:hover, .example:active, .example:focus, .example:before, 
// Now any children of .example and their pseudo selectors
.example *:after, .example *:hover, .example *:active, .example *:focus {
  --example-color: #fff;
}
```

Using a preprocessor like sass/scss helps a lot. My usage of this technique is far too lengthy to show all of it, but this is an overly simplified example of the way I do it.

#### Example Advanced SCSS Method 1

```
// Make a mixin so its easy to repeat
// your css vars/ custom properties
@mixin css-vars($var){
   --var-bg: #{$var};
}

// Defined before using @include
$var: #fff;

.example {

  &,// available to .example
  &::before,
  &::after {
    @include css-vars($var);
    background: var(--var-bg);
  }
}
```

Which would output:

```
.example, .example::before, .example::after {
  --var-bg: #fff;
  background: var(--var-bg);
}
```

#### Example Robust SCSS Method 2

Another method would be nesting a mixin that generates the css vars/custom properties with this mixin's arguments to change values, the prefixes and possible infixes into another mixin in which this mixin is included in your element selector that then defines the scss mixin variable data that gets passed to the generator mixin. (This is useful so you can reuse this generator mixin on other complex css vars/ custom properties on other elements easily -- well sort of easier.)

```
@mixin css-vars-generator(
  $example-prefix,
  $example-infix,
  $example-color
) {
    // Some cool things could happen here,
    // @each loops, color adjustment functions, etc...
    // Only showing some saucy way to customize the actual css var / custom property name
 --#{$example-prefix}-#{$example-infix}-color: #{$example-color};
}

@mixin css-vars(
  $example-color
) {

  // CSS Variables / Custom Properties not inherited or available on pseudo elements from parent elements or :root
  // Must include in them in any pseudo you want to use them
  &,
  & *:before,
  & *:after,
  & *:hover,
  & *:active,
  & *:focus {
    @include css-vars-generator(
      "example-A",
      "var-B",
      $example-color
    );
  }
  // 
}
$example-color:#fff;
.example {
    @include css-vars($example-color);
}
```

Which would ouput:

```
.example, .example*:before, .example*:after, .example*:hover, .example*:active, .example*:focus {
  --example-A-var-B-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I was running some experiments around this issue https://codepen.io/thiagomata/pen/dyawqKJ
and you are correct. The CSS property only goes to the pseudo-element if we set them twice. That was an unexpected and hard-to-find issue, especially when the animations were working because they were unrelated to the pseudo-element.

Comment: @ThiagoMata Yes, it was an unfortunate discovery for me realizing using css vars or custom properties on pseudo selectors means you have add them twice, as **css vars or custom properties are not inherited from parent selector** and some of my collections of css vars became lengthy which increases the size of your stylesheets. In the future I do hope they become inherited.

Answer (score 0):

It is surprising that this question is not closed. Maybe you have a problem with something else, because I reproduced your example - it works

```css
:root{
  --text-color:red;
}

.wrapp {
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.child:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: var(--text-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapp">
  <div class="child">Test</div>
</div>
```