# Are CSS Custom Properties not available to pseudo elements?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-variables

At the head of my page, I have a bunch of CSS Custom Properties that work in all of my stylesheets, however, when I try to access them via `::before`/`::after` pseudo-elements, Chrome states that the variable is not defined.

As an example:

```html
<head>
  ...
  <style>
    :root {
      --my-variable: #ff0000;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

And in my stylesheets:

```css
.box {
  background-color: var(--my-variable); // Works fine
}

.box::after {
  background-color: var(--my-variable); // --my-variable is not defined
}
```

Just wondering if I've missed something?

I've also just noticed it works fine with Firefox, so perhaps it's a bug?

Update: So it seems CSS Properties aren't inherited in pseudo-elements so it needs to be set directly as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72294151/2348814)

Working Example:

```css
:root, *::before, *::after {
  --my-property: xyz;
}
```

Comment: you need to have `content` and add dimension to your pseudo element. This is not related to CSS variables

Comment: Apologies, my actual work contains the correct rules. The above example was only for brevity.

Comment: works fine on chrome/firefox: https://codepen.io/ste-xx/pen/zYprGXw

Comment: It *works* fine, but Chrome Inspector still says `--given-color is not defined` if you select the `.given_class::after` pseudo element in the `Elements` tab, observe the `Styles` pane, and hover your cursor over "`--given-color`" in `content: var(--given-color)` (in your example at https://codepen.io/ste-xx/pen/zYprGXw)

Comment: I second this! While the variable is resolved correctly in the Pseudo Elem. Chrome/Edge still say the variable is undefined despite rendering it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

you must ensure that after the pseudo element defined ::before or ::after, you must defined it the class css attribute `content` with any value different to `none`.